# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' after successful deployment. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, automapper

My app works fine locally on debug and on release mode, but not on deployment.
I deployed the app on our server. and it works ok till I try to use the search function from one of my pages and receive 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. Search work perfectly fine locally.

this is the error that shows up:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Facility.Controllers.Filters.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(Notification
>   s) in
>   C:\LocalSVN\FacilityManagement\Facility\Controllers\Filters\NotificationsFilters.cs:52
>   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +122
>
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +503
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
>   AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumerableMapperBase`1.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +184    AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(ResolutionContext
>   context) +535
>
> [AutoMapperMappingException:
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> IEnumerable`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Facility.Model.Notification,
>   Facility.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Facility.ViewModels.NotificationListVM,
>   Facility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>
> Destination path: IEnumerable`1

Is it something with linq or automapper? how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout your deployment environment configuration, I believe your online db may have absent of the data, where your local db did not. This error message obviously told your code didn't handle how the null to be mapped in this case.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the required part of the form was not filled in in production db.